# Why javascript objects have an extra attribute called Symbol()_a.* in IE11?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, babeljs, symbols

[image: ie11 Symbol()_a.]

Working on a webpage, the strange thing above occurred in IE11. 
Some undefined object **Symbol()_a.** followed by a randowm string got added on each object I created. That broke my application. 
As I didn't find a solution here and IE sucks at debugging I'm posting my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

However I found out, that on a certain stage the babel polyfill was added to the project and caused the issue. 
https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill/

Unfortunately it was not added as the documentation suggests before the compiled babel code. So moving it up solved my issue.

you are welcome :)

Comment: Don't forget to mark your answer as solution if it solved your problem.